# Using Cereal to serialize templated polymorphic types in a library

Tags: c++, templates, cereal

I have a templated base class:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    public:
    T a;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar) {
        ar(a);
    }
};
```

and a templated class that derives from it:

```
template<typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
    public:
    T b;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar) {
        ar(cereal::base_class<A<T>>(this));
        ar(b);
    }
};
```

It is used in another serialized class:

```
template<typename T>
class C {

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar)
    {
        ar(collection);
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A<T>>> collection;
};
```

This code and the code that uses it is compiled into a static lib

From my understanding of the cereal docs I need to add

```
CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(A<double>)
CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(A<float>)

CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(B<double>)
CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(B<float>)
```

etc for each type that will be used, in the header files for each class

This compiles. But has a run time error of

> Trying to save an unregistered polymorphic type (B). Make sure
>   your type is registered with CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE and that the archive
>   you are using was included (and registered with
>   CEREAL_REGISTER_ARCHIVE) prior to calling CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE. If
>   your type is already registered and you still see this error, you may
>   need to use CEREAL_REGISTER_DYNAMIC_INIT.

From the docs I think I need to add `CEREAL_FORCE_DYNAMIC_INIT(libname)` in the headers and `CEREAL_REGISTER_DYNAMIC_INIT` in the CPP file, but there is no cpp file. Or a suitable CPP file to place this in.

Adding `CEREAL_REGISTER_POLYMORPHIC_RELATION` makes no difference as expected as `B`'s serialization function is calling the base calss `A` with `cereal::base_class`
Is there a way to use Cereal to serialize templated classes?

Comment: Sorry, transcription error, missed the <T>.

Comment: The types in your examples don't seem to be polymorphic... are they actually representative of your real code?  If so, that is an odd error

Comment: [Have you followed the documentation](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/polymorphism.html)? Have you used `CEREAL_REGISTER_POLYMORPHIC_RELATION` (if it's needed; I'm totally unfamiliar with cereal)? I agree with xaxxon that the code you posted isn't polymorphic.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/assets/doxygen/polymorphic_8hpp.html#a0479821f6a987e08e7d3f765cda02d91) CEREAL_REGISTER_POLYMORPHIC_RELATION is only required if the subclass does not call the base class with cereal::base_class. Which I am doing.

Comment: Updated to show polymorphic usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue came down to the order of the included headers and where they were included, plus a small amount of RTFM carefully.

In base class header needed:

```
#include <cereal/types/polymorphic.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/portable_binary.hpp>
```

plus any other types I want to serialize to.

Then in subclasses add `CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE` for each supported type.

The key, as noted in the documentation, is that the type of archive is included ***BEFORE*** `CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE`. They do not have to be in the same file as the class declaration. Just include headers before registering types.